# Dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 takes too long to start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, easybcd

Recently I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a 500GB SSD in my laptop (running in legacy mode) so that I could dual boot my laptop and switch between both OSs and do work quickly. Now I have a dual boot setup of Windows 10 with Ubuntu 22.04. I have added one entry for Ubuntu through EasyBCD and the default boot is set to Windows 10.

When I power on my laptop first selecting OS option shown when I click on Windows then the boot works normally, but when I click on Ubuntu it takes too long to start, more than 5 minutes. Afterwards it shows the grub boot menu, and when I select Ubuntu again it once again takes a long time to start and shows this message.

```
[0.3019381 platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: 
(men 6xfed10000 -exfed40fff] E 0.3019541 ACPI MSFT0101:00: 
platform device creation failed: -16
```

and after some time it will start Ubuntu. Once Ubuntu gets started then it works fine. Technically here I don't need the grub bootloader because I already set an entry for Ubuntu through EasyBCD. Also can I uninstall the grub bootloader without creating an issue?

Comment: Is that 22.04? What brand/model system? If so old (over 10 years) to require BIOS/MBR configuration, better to use lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I have also been able to use Kubuntu on 2006 BIOS only laptop with external SSD. Microsoft required vendors to use UEFI/gpt since 2012 with release of Windows 8. Even very old system may have a BIOS update, check vendors support page.